# Convert email header subject to HTML

Tags: php, email, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a PHP script that takes in emails to my support@example.com address and inserts them into my ticket system (or updates).

I'm trying to deal with some special characters I'm getting in the subject line.  Below is the "original headers" of the email

`Subject: [Ticket ID: 2648] =?ISO-8859-1?Q?test=CCng_6?=`

But this is what Gmail shows as the subject (which is correct) `[Ticket ID: 2648] testÌng 6`

How can I decode this in PHP?

(My issue is, I'm summarizing their ticket in the body of the email, and displaying in the subject.  The subject text when displayed in the email appears like `Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?test=CCng_6?=`.  It's also being stored in my db as `=?ISO-8859-1?Q?test=CCng_6?=`.)

Comment: Well you'd want to add MySQL as a tag because you need to be able to store string as unicode/other encoding in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<?php
$subject = "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?= <keld@example.com>";
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($subject)."\n";
?>
```

return: Keld_Jørn_Simonsen <keld@example.com>

and finally you must remove the underscores

```
<?php
$text = '=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?= <keld@example.com>';
echo str_replace('_', '', mb_decode_mimeheader($text)."\n");
?>
```